# Answering old questions that can never be fully answered.

Tags: discussion, bumping

I recently came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/getting-better-at-proofs/7751) from 2010, which basically asks, "How do I get better at coming up with proofs?"  This is an interesting and valuable question, but there's never going to be a final answer; there's always something more to add.  Is it considered acceptable to add my own two cents to such a question?

There are several related questions on the meta about resurrecting old questions (see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/what-is-the-protocol-if-any-for-answering-old-questions) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6403/resurrecting-old-questions)), but as far as I can tell, these all pertain to specific questions with an objectively correct answer.  By contrast, in this case there are *many* good answers that each address some facet of the broad question being asked (for example, one person discusses how to practice, another gives some specific techniques, another recommends a particular book).

To put this another way, if this question were asked for the first time today, I would want to add my answer to the existing ones.  Should the fact that the question is several years old change that?

Comment: *There are too many possible answers* $\implies$ I'm voting to close as *too broad*. (the question, not this meta-question).

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills  It is a broad question, but I don't see how it could be made any narrower.

Comment: If you have something to add, I say, add it.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you don't do this very often I do not see any problem. The question will get bumped to the first page. After a short period of time it is likely that the question will scroll of the bottom of the first page. If not perhaps your answer is awesome.